# Сообщение об общем ответе показывается дважды

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено

1. Перейти на страницу [Задать вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (на мете так же)
2. Отметить флажок 
   *Ответить на собственный вопрос – делитесь знаниями в стиле вопросов и ответов*
3. Отметить флажок *общий*

Предупреждение о неначислении репутации будет показано дважды.

> Вы уверены, что хотите сделать данное сообщение общим для сообщества?  Данный шаг лишает вас прав автора, и вы не сможете больше зарабатывать репутацию, когда сообщение получает голоса «за». Данное решение нельзя будет отменить без помощи модератора.

Похоже, нажатие *Отмена* при первом показе снимает флажок, но второй запрос возникает независимо от этого.

Comment: Точно, есть такое.